# Format timestamp as a date in the tooltip in Vega-lite

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

I have [this chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOmNlADWESlAjEQAXyUB3GsvpoALAAZPS+DTJYaADM3kpwslBsyjSyZGigAB7xIABmNHCCyvqqmHCKIJgAnjh56LkIOGzaSHp2DiCCSIVw2mgA2qDhkdGxyZGCVclpGVnoEIUITGx6SkUl+rJsCDE19kqFQ+mZ+jjaNFB5s8WlIACODEiymHRqNKT29Y3NragdIMjaZvrCsnkOoJhqrIICkqgh2qA0oJci9QDgkNVwegYGxSK0whUimgUjUIHA6gBdJQfL7oSoxTD2An-ApAkFgiEgHB3NiUsYTKYzEDEGoME67faHEBkbRsBg4JgbV4GXIgalE94I0kA476bQMQRCkzTa44PpyXJXbKGB5hCJRGJxTQgNjwqB0KWgSKyaLXOTJHmCPloTyUIJKeGI-QotH5RA4LGoHGCPH1T3e1CeOoBhFIBAQRmyNMnEMtfJ4zVQNkq+ZktgU-LDTIZ6U5PIK34IuAQNmAvlKd3oBBivGovNKKCahH6bsMXsMSmEuzUoA) that takes data from a CSV, pivots it by one of the column and displays several timeseries with lines. Also makes a tooltip taking the names from the pivot column automatically.

[image: stock chart with tooltip and several stock lines]

The only problem is that the date/time appears as a timestamp. Is there a way to format it to look nicer, like an actual date + time, the same way it appears in the X axis?

I know I could specify all the values for the tooltip doing something like

```
        "tooltip": [
    {
        "field": "date",
        "type": "temporal",
        "title": "date",
        "timeUnit": "utcyearmonthdatehoursminutes"
    },
    {...}
]
```

But I want to be able to keep using `"mark": {"type": "rule", "tooltip": {"content": "data"}},` to be able to get the tooltip fields dynamically, and if I add the code above only the date appears in the tooltip.

Here's the full code:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "width": 400,
  "height": 300,
  "encoding": {"x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"}},
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "layer": [
        {"mark": "line"},
        {"transform": [{"filter": {"param": "hover", "empty": false}}], "mark": "point"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"pivot": "symbol", "value": "price", "groupby": ["date"]}],
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "tooltip": {"content": "data"}},
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"value": 0.3, "param": "hover", "empty": false},
          "value": 0
        }
      },
      "params": [{
        "name": "hover",
        "select": {
          "type": "point",
          "fields": ["date"],
          "nearest": true,
          "on": "mouseover",
          "clear": "mouseout"
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can format the date field in calculated transform and assign new field, which will then be displayed in your tooltip.
Just add the below transform code or check the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOmNlADWESlAjEQAXyUB3GsvpoALAAZPS+DTJYaADM3kpwslBsyjSyZGigAB7xIABmNHCCyvqqmHCKIJgAnjh56LkIOGzaSHp2DiCCSIVw2mgA2qDhkdGxyZGCVclpGVnoEIUITGx6SkUl+rJsCDE19kqFQ+mZ+jjaNFB5s8WlIACODEiymHRqNKT29Y3NragdIMjaZvrCsnkOoJhqrIICkqgh2qA0oJci9QDgkNVwegYGxSK0whUimgUjUIHA6gBdJQfL7oSoxTD2An-ApAkFgiEgHB3NiUsYTKYzEDEGoME67faHEBkbRsBg4JgbV4GXIgakKUBQGpQBiNWXoHJwa4IOAAChyDAQlE1AEp8kgIPpIrI0bllAARNR-BUgJWCFVqk4MTBQABiYLU+rUhuNToUAHIAKQAIQABJHlAp4wBNcNmpQWq1yW1wZSxi2xiCAmJxOxE94I0kA476bSqoUmabXHB9OS5K7ZQwPMIRKIl5JseFQOhSxVyaLXOTJHmCPloTyUIJKeGI-QotH5RA4LGoHGCPH1Gdz1CeOrLhFIBCW16gWSXk7rlr5PGCOBQNnV+ZktgU-LDTLXm0Mp5OWvwInARZoICfJKFO6AIGKeKok+ShQK+CL6AhDBId6DzUtSQA). For more format or date expressions refer, https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions

```
"transform": [
        {"pivot": "symbol", "value": "price", "groupby": ["date"]},
        {"calculate": "datetime(datum.date)", "as": "convertedDate"},
        {
          "calculate": "utcFormat(datum.date,'%B %d, %Y')",
          "as": "converted as string"
        }
      ],
```

If you want to update the existing date field, then just provide the date field in `as` config as done below:

```
 {"calculate": "datetime(datum.date)", "as": "date"},
```

Comment: This is definitely an improvement but the original human-unfriendly "date" is still shown at the top of the tooltip.  Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: you can format that tooltip `date` field as well using the `format` config

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it in the following way:

- Deleted "tooltip" from "mark" and put it into "encoding":

  ```
   "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "width": "container",
    "data": { "values" : {{dataViz2 | safe }} },                          
    "mark": { "type":"line",  
               "point": {"filled": false,"fill": "white"}
            },                                    
    "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal",  "axis": {"format": "%b %d "}},
    "y": {"field": "total", "type": "quantitative"},
    "tooltip": [
    {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "format": "%b %d %Y"},
    {"field": "total", "type": "quantitative", "format": ",d" }
    ]                            
    }
  ```